# Check if array cell has a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm grabbing a string of data where each element pair is delimited by the ';' character. So, I do a string split into an array to get each chunk of data.

Each chunk now consists of a label and value pair, which are delimited by a ':'. However, every so often the final element doesn't have a matching value. So for example:

```
food:cheese
name:dave
car:renault
somethingelse
```

I'm grabbing these pairs and splitting them into a second array which I then iterate via a foreach like so;

```
int a=0;
            string[,] tmpInfo = new string[10, 2];
            foreach(var info in details)
            {
                string[] tmp = info.Split(':');

                if (tmp[1].ToString != null)
                {
                  //do something
                }
             }
```

However, when I hit the odd scenario where the last element doesn't have the delimiter, I get an issue with "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

As you can see from my code I tried testing if the array cell was null. I've also tried testing for an empty string, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your check `if (tmp[1].ToString != null)` , check for the `Length` of returned array like:

```
if(tmp.Length == 2) //if it should always be 2
```

In case of empty string or no delimiter in the string you would end up with 1 element in the array. Later when you try to access element at index `1`, you will get exception since arrays are `0` based and `tmp[1]` means access second element of the returned array.

Comment: Thanks. I had also tried against the length of the cell, but that again returned an error. I guess you have to test if the cell exists before you can test against it directly. Ill give this a try.